# Android Camera API doesn't show image in directory after capturing?

Tags: android, android-camera

I made my own android camera app using Java, and everything seems to work fine except that when i capture an image, it doesnt display in my directory -until- I delete one or more excisting files from that same directory. Do you guys have any idea why this is happening?

I've looked at my directory through my phone image gallery, and in Windows 10 file manager (via USB cable).

This is my code:

CameraDemo.java

```
package nl.arjenvangaal.takepicturev2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraDemo extends Activity {
    Preview preview;
    Button saveButton;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //load layout file

        preview = new Preview(this); //create new camera preview
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview); //display new preview

        //button listener
        saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            }
        });

    }

    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {

        }
    };

    /** Handles data for raw picture */
    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        }
    };


    /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss", Locale.US);
            String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            String photoFile = "Foto_"+ date + ".jpg";
            File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); //mapje

            String filename =sdDir + File.separator + photoFile; //mapje + / + filenaam
            File pictureFile = new File(filename);  //uiteindelijke bestandslocatie

            FileOutputStream outStream; //me create new output

            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Foto opgeslagen.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Foto kon niet worden opgeslagen.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Preview.java

```
package nl.arjenvangaal.takepicturev2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    public Camera camera;

    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        camera = Camera.open();
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90); //Roteer het beeld 90 graden zodat het goed wordt weergegeven
            camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                    Preview.this.invalidate();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        camera.stopPreview();
;
        //voorkom error als je het programma afsluit en heropent
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
        Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(0); // .... select one of previewSizes here
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);

        //voorkom error als je het programma afsluit en heropent
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //You can ignore this, because this means the Preview doesn't Exist
            //So, no need to try stopping
        }
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Catch this
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        Paint p= new Paint(Color.RED);
        Log.d(TAG, "draw");
        canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, p);
    }
}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "it doesnt display in my directory" -- please explain how you are looking for the file. DDMS? `adb shell`? On-device file manager? Desktop OS file manager via USB cable? Something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare I've looked at my directory through my phone image gallery, and in Windows 10 file manager (via USB cable).